# How to have spans not line-break, but the paragraph still line-break, in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, whitespace

As shown below and at https://jsfiddle.net/a6b37kx6/1/ I have a `<p>` which has been divided into `<span>`. It is Japanese, and there are no spaces in the text. I don't want line breaks to happen within a span, so I use `.word {white-space:nowrap;}` in the CSS.  (The width and border on the P tag are just to save you having to resize your browser to see the problem; in the real application the paragraph width would be auto.)

This works as expected in Firefox:

[image]

but in Chrome using `white-space:nowrap` on the spans means it appears as one long line. Is this a Chrome bug, and even if it is, is there a workaround?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
html {font-size:20px;}
p {width:10rem;border:1px solid black;}
.word {white-space:nowrap;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>
<span class="word">営業</span><span class="word">利益</span><span class="word">予想</span><span class="word">を</span><span class="word">８０億円</span><span class="word">から</span><span class="word">５０億円</span><span class="word">に</span><span class="word">減額</span><span class="word">修正</span><span class="word">する</span><span class="word">。</span>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: BTW, I found https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/ interesting, but couldn't get any of those tricks to change Chrome's behaviour here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is a bug in chrome or something else causing chrome to behave like this.

However, by default, `<span>` is an `inline` element. Just make it `inline-block` and problem will be fixed.

```
.word {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```css
html {font-size:20px;}
p {width:10rem;border:1px solid black;}
.word {
  white-space:nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="word">営業</span><span class="word">利益</span><span class="word">予想</span><span class="word">を</span><span class="word">８０億円</span><span class="word">から</span><span class="word">５０億円</span><span class="word">に</span><span class="word">減額</span><span class="word">修正</span><span class="word">する</span><span class="word">。</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Wonderful! That also solved a problem I was having with nested spans (the nested span was showing on the previous line)!